# Visual studio showing fake errors after build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, syntax-error

I'm on Visual Studio 2017.  After building the `.sln` in debug mode, I'm getting errors.  However, when I visit the error by double clicking the error from the error list tab, the error disappears from the page and also the bug count reduces.

[image: (error list)]

I'm not too sure of this behavior and why this happening. There are 2k+ errors and I don't want to visit every page to remove the error.

Comment: try cleaning the solution/project.

Comment: try change Build + IntelliSense by Build only

Comment: Try with Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: This is likely an issue in VS: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3680

Comment: This can happen if you have a particular file open at the time. For example an ARM json file may have errors in but it doesn't effect the build.

Answer (score 1):

This is has been going on for years (ie...not related to VS2017).   For me, this is usually solved by closing VS and deleting the .suo file that is hidden in the project directory, but there are several ways it has been solved by others that may help you as well (the aforementioned clean/rebuild being one of them).   Here is another SO question/answer that details more in-depth the majority of the solutions all in 1 place.

[Visual studio showing fake errors after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596007/visual-studio-showing-fake-errors-after-build)

Answer (score 0):

For me this was resolved going from .net framework 4.5 to 4.8